# Why does using the amsmath package break the following code?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am trying to find a way to hide expressions inside a math environment. I found a solution, provided by Steven B. Segletes at

[Hiding part of text leaving blank space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135453/hiding-part-of-text-leaving-blank-space/135479#135479)

However, when I add the amsmath package, it breaks, giving me the error "Missing $ inserted". I have provided a MWE example below. If I remove `\usepackage{amsmath}`, it compiles. If I remove the `\frac` command it compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\censorruleheight=0ex

\makeatletter
\long\def\blackout#1{%
 \def~{-}%
 \protected@edef\save@arg{#1}%
 \expandafter\censor@Block\save@arg\stringend\let~\sv@tilde}
 \let\sv@cenword\@cenword
\newcommand\m@cenword[1]{\ThisStyle{%
\stackengine{\mcensorruledepth}{$\SavedStyle\phantom{#1}$}%
{\rule{\widthof{$\SavedStyle#1$}}{\the\censorruleheight}}{U}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\newcommand\mblackout[2][\dp\strutbox]{%
 \let\@cenword\m@cenword%
\def\mcensorruledepth{#1}%
\blackout{{#2}}%
\let\@cenword\sv@cenword%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[\mblackout{\frac{a}{b}} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your code says `amsmath`, your text, title and tag says `amsthm`, I assume you meant to have `amsmath` everywhere?

Comment: this has nothing to do with `amsmath`.  *any* math substituted in the `\mblackout` expression will fail.  comment out `amsmath` and change the display line to `\[ \mblackout{\alpha} \]` -- that results in the same `Missing $ inserted.`, and inserting `$` signs as `\[ \mblackout{$\alpha$} \]` results in the error `Missing } inserted.`  so no, there is something wrong with your definitions, which i haven't got time to debug.

Comment: Why not use `\color{white}{Text to be hidden here}` like one of the other solutions in [Hiding part of text leaving blank space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135453/hiding-part-of-text-leaving-blank-space/135479)

Comment: You are right that it does not work with `\alpha` and most other math commands. However,it is not correct that any math substituted into `\mblackout` fails. It works with `\frac` without amsmath, but not with. I assume amsmath redefines `\frac` in some way?  I do not want to use `\color{white}` (which was my original solution) because I am blanking out text on the students' version of my notes and I decided I do not want them to be able to copy the hidden text (also, I do not always have a white background).

Comment: When I try `\[1+\mblackout{1\alpha}+1\]`, the code compiles correctly with no errors. The code does not compile correctly (and with the same error message as before) when I try `\[1+\mblackout{\alpha}+1\]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 4.2 of the `censor` package, the censoring of math *text* is handled somewhat automatically.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{censor}
%\censorruleheight=0ex
\begin{document}
\[y = \blackout{x = \frac{a_{1}}{b_{2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \]

\[y = x = \frac{a_1}{b_2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \]

$\beta / \blackout{\alpha} \times 3$

$\beta / \alpha \times 3$
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Note several points: 1) non-text macros like `\frac` are not censored, per se, but only the numerator and denominator *text* are censored (thus the vinculum shows), and 2) censored sub- and superscripts must be embraced even when a single token.

Therefore, for the current question, where the `\censorruleheight` can be set to `0pt`, the vinculum remains:

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can set the offending macros in their own group (via braces) and then they set just fine, with or without `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\censorruleheight=0ex

\makeatletter
\long\def\blackout#1{%
 \def~{-}%
 \protected@edef\save@arg{#1}%
 \expandafter\censor@Block\save@arg\stringend\let~\sv@tilde}
 \let\sv@cenword\@cenword
\newcommand\m@cenword[1]{\ThisStyle{%
\stackengine{\mcensorruledepth}{$\SavedStyle\phantom{#1}$}%
{\rule{\widthof{$\SavedStyle#1$}}{\the\censorruleheight}}{U}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\newcommand\mblackout[2][\dp\strutbox]{%
 \let\@cenword\m@cenword%
\def\mcensorruledepth{#1}%
\blackout{{#2}}%
\let\@cenword\sv@cenword%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[y = \mblackout{x = {\frac{a}{b}}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \]

\[y = x = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \]

$\beta / \mblackout{{\alpha}} \times 3$

$\beta / \alpha \times 3$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem in my original question with `\alpha` and the like. However it does not work across alignment and new line characters (which is what I was hoping for). So, unless there is some way to modify the definition of `\mblackout` to remove this necessity,  simply using `\phantom` as suggested by barbara beeton is preferable for blanking math, since it does not require one to put things in braces. (Although your solution does have the advantage of being easily modifiable to allow for blacking out and underlining - this flexibility may prove useful to me.)

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes, Ever since I updated to Version 4.2 of the censor package, this solution does not work for me anymore (not sure which version I used before). Do you happen to have an updated solution that works for math expressions via the new xblackout environment or with an updated \newcommand\mblackout  ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Raphael You shouldn't need a redefinition of `\blackout` and a separate `\mblackout` macro.  The new version handles the text of math already.  In fact, extra braces are not even required now: `\begin{document}
\[y = \blackout{x = \frac{a}{b}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \]

\[y = x = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \]

$\beta / \blackout{\alpha} \times 3$

$\beta / \alpha \times 3$
\end{document}` works.

Comment: @Raphael See my updated answer, as well as the censor v4.2 package documentation (section 6).

Answer (score 3):

why don't you just use `\phantom{...}`?
`\phantom` never puts anything but (precisely measured) space on a page.

of course, you'll have to be careful about keeping things like `&` and other
formatting instructions in proper synch, but it should be reasonably obvious
how to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ abc\phantom{def}ghi \]

first, the example without \verb+\phantom+s:
\begin{align*}
 abc &= def\\
 ghi &= \frac{1}{m}jklmnopq\\
 rst &> \frac{1}{2}

\end{align*}
this even works in $abc\tfrac{1}{1+n}de$ in-line text.

now, apply \verb+\phantom+ to selected elements:
\begin{align*}
 abc &= def\\
 g\phantom{h}i &= \phantom{\frac{1}{m}}jk\phantom{lmn}opq\\
 rs\phantom{t} &> \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
this even works in $ab\phantom{c\tfrac{1}{1+n}}de$ in-line text.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: It doesn't work across the alignment character `&` or the new line character \\ in aligned equations. I was hoping for a solution that would (so as to not have to put the command around each part of the expression separately). Is this possible? I am not sure that even a solution with the censor package will work.  I also wanted to find out what was wrong with the code from the answer to the previous question about hiding math.

Comment: you are correct that it will work only *within* a "cell".  if you have many, many instances of this to change, then a "comment"-type approach might be worth the effort.  but for just a few, you are attacking a flea with a bludgeon.  sorry i can't help with debugging the code you posted, but it's really nontrivial, and i'm not a user of any of the packages you load, except for `amsmath`.  regarding your earlier comment, yes, `amsmath` does redefine `\frac` (to add functionality).

Comment: Ideally I would like something like `\visible` in Beamer (which does work almost everywhere: across alignment characters, figures and tables, around list environments). But the way it is done there (I have not yet looked into how the overlay commands are defined) may only work due to things being put in frames.