# Can I use phantom to hide a LaTeX environment (itemize)?

Tags: environments

Is there a way I can use `\phantom` to hide the contents of an environment, such as `itemize`?

This does not execute:

```
\phantom{\begin{itemize}
          \item Hi!
         \end{itemize}}
```

I'm specifically not looking to just change the text white, because I don't want the contents highlightable in the output.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135453/hiding-part-of-text-leaving-blank-space help?

Comment: @egreg Wow!  Not only is that relevant because it's working to leave the space open, I also want this functionality for student versions of my lecture notes.  Wild!  Nice find!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't use `\phantom` like that. You can use a `\parbox` inside \phantom to hide the contents, but reserving the space it occupied, or you could use the `comment` environment from the [`comment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package to hide the contents suppressing the space altogether:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

a
\begin{comment}
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{comment}
b

a\par
\noindent\phantom{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}}}\par
b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!  I need to get more used to using parboxes to turn "block" elements into "inline" elements.  (I'm guessing at terms here.)  Thank you!