# Making an environment with the same text color as the background

Tags: math-mode, color, environments

I am looking to type up some solutions to math problems.  However, I do not want someone who just looks at the document to be able to see the solution; I want the students to be able to see the problem without the solution.

How can I create an environment that has the text color the same as the background color?

As an added wrinkle, I do need the color to carry over to the math environment.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are many existing packages that solve this exact problem (although I don't think they use the method of changing the text color). The one I use (its actually a class file) is called `exam` and its documentation is here: http://ctan.org/pkg/exam

Comment: Changing the color would not work if the students have the electronic version.  The data would still be in the document.  This answer might give ideas: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135453/hiding-part-of-text-leaving-blank-space/135479#135479

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there are classes or packages that are probably more suitable solutions (I usually use the `exam` class). However, one option is to create an environment that sets the color to be the same as the background. Here's an example in a `tcolorbox`, then again by itself. In the latter case you could just use `\color{white}` to hide the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\colorlet{mycolor}{blue!20!white}
\tcbset{colback=mycolor}

\newenvironment{mysolution}
{ Solution:\par\color{mycolor} }
{ \color{black} }

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Problem:

Some problem statement.
\tcblower
\begin{mysolution}
The solution

\begin{equation}
x=2
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{mysolution}
\end{tcolorbox}

Problem:

A different problem

\begin{mysolution}
\begin{equation}
y=x^{2}
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{mysolution}
\end{document}
```

[image]